# How to place 2 images in Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put 2 images - one over the other on a marker.
But shadow is not good as the google maps can't overlay one each other.

How can I put 2 icons?

```
myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLong,
                map: map,
                shadow: '/images/map-shadow.png',
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
            });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the complex icon example in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#ComplexIcons)

Comment: this is using SHADOW. I intentionally do not want to use shadow becuase it has a different rendering behavior